# IntelliJ Open API usage outside of plugin development

Tags: java, intellij-plugin

How can I use the classes of IntelliJ Open API that perform the analysis of the Java code and its conversion to Tree Nodes? I am referring to those being used in plugin development, but I want to exploit them separately out of the scope of plugin development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to look at community editon? It's opensource and you can debug it easily. (but I'm not sure it has Open API though) http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/Download

Answer (score 0):

The core of OpenAPI was recently used in the `UpSource` project, check it out:

https://upsource.jetbrains.com/